# How to stream AWS Lambda response in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function, and I need to invoke it from my node app and stream the result back to the client.  I've looked in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) but can't see a way.  I want to do something like this:

```
lambda.invoke(params).then(data => data.pipe(res))
```

or even

```
lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
  // data should be a pipeable stream instead of buffered
  data.pipe(res)
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Javascript AWS SDK supports streaming the body of the API responses](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/692e005ace60b3b4725513499566f4d2ddf0ce5e/lib/request.js#L532-L548) so API calls like getting a large S3 blob of binary data can be streamed *to* Javascript functions.

```
lambda.invoke(lambdaDef)
  .createReadStream()
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("Got data:", data.toString())
  })
```

You'll get the `Payload` of the response as `data`.

Response Streaming for the [lambda functions themselves was added in 2023](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html). For the Node.js 14.x, 16.x and 18.x managed runtimes or a custom runtime, via either a [Function URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) or when using the AWS SDK directly like above. (Thanks @Eric)

```
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises')

exports.handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(
  async (event, response_stream, _context) => {
    const data = createSomeReadStream()
    await pipeline(data, responseStream)
  }
)
```

Comment: Does anyone know if it's still true that Node.js lambda functions do not support streaming?

Comment: I haven't used lambda for a while, had a look through the docco when updating the links but it looks the same as before. Maybe if you could inject the `AWS.Request` that returns from lambda? It has some options related to streaming.

Comment: 2023 update -- Lambda supports streaming with chunked formats now too: https://ehotinger.com/blog/a-tour-of-aws-lambda-response-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

Lambda started to support via Lambda function URLs. API Gateway doesn't support this yet.
This is only supported for Node.js for now.

Sample:

```js
const pipeline = require("util").promisify(require("stream").pipeline);
const { Readable } = require('stream');
    
exports.echo = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
  // As an example, convert event to a readable stream.
  const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event)));
    
  await pipeline(requestStream, responseStream);
});
```

[Configuring a Lambda function to stream responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html)