# Is it possible to stream a response from a Python AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, streaming

It is possible to have a Python Lambda in AWS that can stream the HTTP response back to the client?

The use case is to stream some data out of Elasticsearch, transform it to CSV, and stream it straight back to the client (via the API Gateway).

From what I can make out, this is possible in Java (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382131/17641) and probably also possible in Node, but I can't see how to do this in Python.

Comment: Last time I looked into this it was not possible. Holding out for other answers though.

Comment: you mentioned that it is probably possible to do in Nodejs. I cant find any source for this. Can you please add if it is possible with nodejs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052588/aws-lambda-send-partial-response/57054919

Comment: Its only possible to stream the response as the client, not in lambda itself

Answer (score 1):

AWS has recently (April 2023) introduced Lambda response streaming:
[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/)

Note at the time of launch only **node runtimes** support this feature.

There are other caveats too, so reading the above article thoroughly is recommended.

Comment: I see "You can also implement response streaming using custom runtimes." in the AWS. Is it possible we could implement this for Python?

Comment: @AlexRamalho you can probably reverse engineer it from the nodejs implementation. Lambda runtime (RIC) calls are language agnostic. But are you sure you need it? For what?

Comment: I need it for answering via streaming answer from a Langchain/OpenAI logic encapsulate in FastAPI (Python)